# What is difference between an identification scheme and a digital signature scheme?

Tags: signature, terminology, schnorr-identification

It seems we can use every identification scheme to sign and verify a message and vice versa. I am right or not? What is difference between an identification scheme and a digital signature scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh, I was just reading about this.

Quoting [1]:

> **Identification schemes:** A can prove to B that he is A, but B cannot
> prove to someone
>
> **Signature schemes:** A can prove to B that he is A, but
> B cannot prove even to himself
>
> **The distinction between identification and signature schemes is
> subtle, and manifests itself mainly when the proof is interactive and
> the verifier later wants to prove its existence to a judge**: In
> identification schemes B can create a credible transcript of an
> imaginary communication by carefully choosing both the questions and
> the answers in the dialog, while in signature schemes only real
> communication with A could generate a credible transcript. **However, in
> many commercial and military applications the main problem is to
> detect forgeries in real time and to deny the service, access or
> response that the forger wants. In these cases the transcript and
> judge are irrelevant, and the two types of schemes can be used
> interchangeably.**

[1]: Fiat, A., & Shamir, A. (1986, August). How to prove yourself: Practical solutions to identification and signature problems. In Conference on the Theory and Application of Cryptographic Techniques (pp. 186-194). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and of course the reference. I think also have to read it.